# GUI / wallet stuck on block 1400001

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I reinstalled my monero wallet hoping it would fix the problem, but every time i start my wallet it's stuck at 58928 blocks to sync up. My wallet had no problems syncing up in the past and no mather how long i keep the wallet open it won't sync. the node reports this problem: (i don't know if this information helps?) But basically my wallet won't work if it doesn't sync up.

INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 1400001/1458929 (96.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 259.32 MH/s, v5, update needed, 7(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 10h 40m 31s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a "hard" upgrade at that height, older clients will not sync.

Get the latest version at: https://getmonero.org/downloads/

and run it, it will find the old blockchain and simply continue.

If you're still stuck, you can delete last few blocks from your database and try from there. Close your node, run `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 5` (it's a separate executable in the package) and restart the node. It will then continue from 1399996 and hopefully go past the upgrade block.

Comment: Thank you very much. Downloaded the newest version and there seems to be some movement going on :) Fingers crossed hoping it will go all the way. Thanks for the info ;)

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to StackExchange. If it solved your problem, please don't forget to mark the question as accepted ;)